# Undefined method, using PDO outside the class

Tags: php, class, pdo, namespaces

I'm getting following error when trying to run query outside the connection class.

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined method Core\Database::query() in...

I have following files.

**Database.php**

```
namespace Core;

use \PDO;

class Database
{
    private $pdo;
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;", "root", "pw");
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new Database();
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
namespace Auth;

use Core\Database;

class Auth
{
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = Database::getInstance();
        $query = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Like the error says, you do not have a query method in your Database class.  getInstance() returns an instance of the Database class, not PDO.

Comment: @Devon, ok: I changed `$this->dbh->query` to `$this->dbh->pdo->query` in Auth.php, but is there any other way? It looks a bit mess.

Comment: Also, make the  instance variable `$pdo` *public*, otherwise you won't be able to access it outside of the class, especially when you're calling `->query(...)` from `Auth` class.

Comment: Singleton DB objects are a code smell. Construct a PDO object normally and pass it in via the constructor of the Auth object. http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection

Comment: Did you resolve the issue with any of the given answers? If one was useful up vote and if it resolved, mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a property of the database class and returning a static value. Perhaps you might want to do this instead:

```
class Database extends \PDO{
  public static function getInstance(){
    if(!self::$instance){
      self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function __construct(){
    try {
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;", "root", "pw", [
          \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]);

        self::$instance = $this;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Personally I have done this instead of creating a silly wrapper class.

Otherwise you will have to set the static variable instead:

```
self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;", "root", "pw");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done in `Auth` class is you've just created the instance of `Database` class using the `Singleton` pattern and trying to invoke the `query` method from the `Database` instance which is not defined in the class. If you want to access it like `$this->dbh->query()`, you need to construct an instance of `Database` class and return the `PDO` instance at the same time. Like this one:

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
        self::$instance = new Database();
    return self::$instance->pdo;
}
```

What I've just modified here is `return self::$instance->pdo`. This returns the object of `PDO` once the `Database` class is instantiated if the `getInstance` is invoked for first time otherwise it just returns the created `PDO` instance. You can now do `$this->dbh->query()` in `Auth` class.

Note, you need to do this only if you're not going to define any other methods in the `Database` class except `static` methods like `getInstance`. Because the result of `getInstance` only allows you to access `PDO` properties and methods. So, the solution for that is to define a `public` method in `Database` which returns `PDO` instance separately.

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
        self::$instance = new Database();
    return self::$instance;
}

public function getPDO() {
    return $this->pdo;
}
```

Once you're done with it, you can access the `PDO` in `Auth` class like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbh = Database::getInstance()->getPDO();
    $query = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table");
}
```

Hope it helps!